# View all data from multiple tables (html / php)

Tags: php, html

I would like to be able to display in a structured way the data coming from my tables. Let me explain, I want to recover in a first table x data and do the same thing in a second table but I would like the display to face successively:
first line -> first table data - second table data
second line -> data first table - data second table
...

My function for connection to my BDD:

```
<?php
   function connexionPDO(){
       $login = "root";
       $mdp = "";
       $bd = "test_tuto";
       $serveur = "localhost";
       try{
           $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=$bd", $login, $mdp);
           return $conn;
       }catch(PDOException $e){
           print "Erreur de connexion PDO";
           die(); // On peut également faire un return null
       }
   }
?>
```

My test is not working:

```
<?php

$pdo = connexionPDO();


//$reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM profil WHERE pseudo_profil=\'' . $_GET['pseudo'] . '\' order by datemesure desc');
 $reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT p.datemesure, p.nom, p.profession, p.tel, p.email, p.conducteur, 
 p.circonstance, p.proces, p.vehiculeAssure, p.degats, p.blesses, p.dateAccident, p.lieu, p.gps, 
 p.pseudo_profil, f.photo_name, f.signature_name, f.caption FROM profil p LEFT OUTER JOIN photo f 
  ON  f.caption=p.pseudo_profil ORDER BY p.datemesure desc');

  // On affiche chaque entrée une à une
   while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
   {

    ?>
        <div class="encadrement">

        <p class="encadrement_e"> Date d'enregistrement : <?php echo $donnees['datemesure']; ?> </p> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom du propriétaire du véhicule : </strong><?php echo $donnees['nom']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Profession : </strong><?php echo $donnees['profession']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Numéro de téléphone : </strong><?php echo $donnees['tel']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $donnees['email']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom du conducteur: </strong><?php echo $donnees['conducteur']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Circonstance de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['circonstance']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>procès verbal établi ? </strong><?php echo $donnees['proces']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Le véhicule est-il assuré ? </strong><?php echo $donnees['vehiculeAssure']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Dégats de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['degats']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom et nombre des blessés : </strong><?php echo $donnees['blesses']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Date de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['dateAccident']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Lieu de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['lieu']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Données GPS : </strong><?php echo $donnees['gps']; ?> </br>
        <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Pseudo du propriétaire du compte : </strong><?php echo $donnees['pseudo_profil']; ?> </br>

        </div>
    <?php
    }

?>
```

In my 2 tables there are 4 lines and it shows me each line of my tables "profile" 4 times, which is not normal at all.
If anyone can bring me some solutions, I'll be really happy.
Good end of day to all.

Comment: Well a table join is usually done on primary key columns or columns containing unique data. Its possible that the caption and pseudo_profil fields do not contain unique data. Because of this duplicate data may be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Nadir and thank you for responding so early. Actually, I did not know this properties there on the table joins. So I skirted as follows, and it's not very professional but it works:

```html
$reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM profil WHERE profil.pseudo_profil=\'' . $_GET['pseudo'] . '\' order by datemesure desc');
   $reponse2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM photo WHERE photo.caption=\'' . $_GET['pseudo'] . '\' order by id desc');
   
   ?><div class="encadrement"><?php
    
    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {
   ?>
     <p class="encadrement_e"> Date d'enregistrement : <?php echo $donnees['datemesure']; ?> </p> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom du propriétaire du véhicule : </strong><?php echo $donnees['nom']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Profession : </strong><?php echo $donnees['profession']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Numéro de téléphone : </strong><?php echo $donnees['tel']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $donnees['email']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom du conducteur: </strong><?php echo $donnees['conducteur']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Circonstance de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['circonstance']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>procès verbal établi ? </strong><?php echo $donnees['proces']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Le véhicule est-il assuré ? </strong><?php echo $donnees['vehiculeAssure']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Dégats de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['degats']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom et nombre des blessés : </strong><?php echo $donnees['blesses']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Date de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['dateAccident']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Lieu de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees['lieu']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Données GPS : </strong><?php echo $donnees['gps']; ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Pseudo du propriétaire du compte : </strong><?php echo $donnees['pseudo_profil']; ?> </br>
     <?php 
      $donnees2 = $reponse2->fetch();
     ?>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom de la photo de l'accident : </strong><?php echo $donnees2['photo_name'];?></br><?php
     echo '<a href="phone/upload_photo/'.$donnees2['photo_name'].'"><img class="encadrement_e3" src="phone/upload_photo/'.$donnees2['photo_name'].'" alt="photo accident" title="Cliquez pour agrandir"/></a>';
     ?> </br>
     <p class="encadrement_e2"/> <strong>Nom de la signature : </strong><?php echo $donnees2['signature_name'];?></br><?php
     echo '<a href="phone/upload_signature/'.$donnees2['signature_name'].'"><img class="encadrement_e3" src="phone/upload_signature/'.$donnees2['signature_name'].'" alt="photo signature" title="Cliquez pour agrandir"/></a>';
     ?> </br>
     
     
     <div class="espace"> </div>
     
    <?php
    }
    $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
    
   ?></div><?php
```